# Entity Framework 4.0: How to log sql statements

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, log4net

I am using Entity Framework 4.0 in the application how to print log of sql statements .In EF 6 sampleEntities.Database.Log is working as below

```
readonly log4net.ILog log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);
public sampleEntities()
    : base("name=sampleEntities")
{
    this.Database.Log = s => log.Info("LINQSQLLOG : " + s);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it as shown below.

**Method 1 :**

```
IQueryable myQuery = from x in yourEntities
             where y.id = 45 
             select y;

var sql = ((System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery)myQuery).ToTraceString();
```

**Method 2 :**

You can use `Clutch.Diagnostics.EntityFramework` API. It provides API for tracing EntityFramework sql commands.

**Nuget :**

```
PM > Install-Package Clutch.Diagnostics.EntityFramework
```

API on Git : [**Clutch API**](https://github.com/Kukkimonsuta/Clutch)

**Update :** [**Logging and Tracing SQL Queries Clutch**](http://girl-programmer.blogspot.de/2013/03/logging-and-tracing-sql-queries-using.html)

Comment: thanks for replay i will try second one .is it posssible to log all sql staments Clutch.Diagnostics.EntityFramework because some results are list as below var Reminder= context.Reminders.ToList(); ?